# Is there anything to change the exports name mangling scheme in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, name-mangling

I'm trying to build a project I have and it has several exported functions. The functions follow the stdcall convention and they get mangled if compiled with GCC as

```
Func@X
```

Other compilers mangle the name like this:

```
_Func@X
```

Is any way I can force GCC to mangle the names of the exported functions to the later example?

Answer (score 4):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034852/adding-leading-underscores-to-assembly-symbols-with-gcc-on-win32/1035937#1035937).

```
int Func() __asm__("_Func@X");
```

This will force GCC to name the symbol `_Func@X` regardless of what it would have done normally.

---

Oh right, `@` is special: it's used for symbol versioning.  I thought that `__asm__("...@...")` used to work, but I guess it doesn't anymore.

```
int Func() __asm__("_Func");
__asm__(".symver _Func, _Func@X");
```

This must be accompanied by a [version script](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_25.html) file, like:

```
1 {
  global:
    _Func;
};
```

given to `gcc -Wl,--version-script=foo.version` when linking.

Comment: Thanks, but either I am doing something wrong or it doesn't work, it won't let me link it. http://pastebin.com/f14a9a00f

Answer (score 0):

See the GCC manual regarding [-fleading-underscore](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html).  Do read the warnings about the consequences of this action however; it may not be the solution you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though it doesn't seem to work, so the standard in C is not to use the leading underscore? I was trying to make it kind of portable among compilers, the functions are exports of a DLL which need to be loaded.

Comment: Are you compiling the code as C or C++?  For compiler interoperability, the DLL must only present C interfaces.  You can use C++, but the interfaces should be declared extern "C" (and of course only use C compatable types, and no function overloading).

Answer (score 0):

The best bet when dealing with function name mangling on Windows is to always use a `.def` file. This will work the same regardless of the compiler. Typically you only need the `EXPORTS` section:

```
EXPORTS
  Func1
  Func2
  ...
```