# How do you build a C program that includes the entry point on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, entry-point

How do you build a C program that includes the entry point on Mac OS X?

I want to build:

```
start() {
    /* exit system call */
    asm("movl $1,%eax;"
        "xorl %ebx,%ebx;"
        "int  $0x80"
    );
}
```

but when I run:

```
gcc -nostdlib min.c
```

I always get:

```
ld: could not find entry point "start" (perhaps missing crt1.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The one other attempt I made just to see what it was doing was run:

```
gcc -nostdlib -c min.c && otool -tV min.o
```

And the output was:

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
_start:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp,%rbp
0000000000000004    leave
0000000000000005    ret
```

So where did that underscore come from before the "start" function? How do I prevent that from happening? Or more simply:

How do you build a C program that includes the entry point on Mac OS X?

Thanks,
CrazyChenz

Comment: _start is a mangled name, probably.  Before you create a start, be aware that there is a lot of preprocessing that has to go on or all sorts of problems will break.  To get an idea of symbols you have to define try nm crt1.o.  gcc -e main  makes "main" the entry point instead of start. You can define any function you want this way.  I do not know how to set that option for Xcode.  Someone else might.

Comment: IIRC, MacOS call numbers are different from Linux, so eax=1 / int 0x80 might not be sys_exit.  And 32-bit system MacOS calls take their args on the stack FreeBSD style, not EBX, ECX, EDX, ....  And of course if making a 64-bit executable, you'll want to use `syscall` with appropriate call numbers / arg-passing regs for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gcc -e option defines the entry point, when you want the entry point to be something other than start.  This way you can create mystart() as you entry point.

```
gcc -e mystart mycode.c -o mycode
```

I do not know how to set the -e option in Xcode.

Comment: MacOS mangles names with a leading `_` so I think you'd need `gcc -e _mystart`.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the symbol that gcc gives to the function by declaring it separately with `asm`:

```
void start() asm ("start");
```

Make sure this is a standalone declaration, separate from the function definition.

You can read more details about controlling the generated symbol here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1035937/12928775

Also, as Peter Cordes points out, you should probably include `__attribute__((naked))` on the function definition to prevent gcc from generating a stack frame on entry.

The full code would be:

```
void start() asm ("start");

__attribute__((naked)) void start() {
    /* exit system call */
    asm("movl $1,%eax;"
        "xorl %ebx,%ebx;"
        "int  $0x80"
    );
}
```

Comment: You don't need `extern` in the prototype.  https://godbolt.org/z/Vz77nS shows that `void start(void) asm("_mystart");` produces the specified name.  Also, you probably want `void` instead of using legacy C implicit-`int`.  And `__attribute__((naked))` would be a good idea for the definition; `start` isn't a function so you don't want -O0 to make a stack frame on entry.

Comment: For extra bonus points, remember that `()` in C (unlike C++) leaves the arg types unspecified, not like `(void)`.  Might as well be specific that it doesn't take any args.