# Make a small mach-o executable with C

Tags: c, macos, assembly

For curiosity's sake, I'm trying to see what's the smallest that I can make a C program with a minimum of assembly language. I want to see if I can make a simple OpenGL demo (i.e. demo scene) using OpenGL and GLUT linked dynamically, without the standard library. However, I'm running into trouble with the most basic stuff.

I've created a test main.c file that contains

```
void newStart() {
  //Do stuff here...

  asm("movl $1, %eax;"
      "xorl %ebx, %ebx;"
      "int  $0x80;");
}
```

and I'm making it with

```
gcc main.c -nostdlib -e newStart -o min
```

using the '-e' option as recommended by [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353928/how-do-you-build-a-c-program-that-includes-the-entry-point-on-mac-os-x). I get the following error when I try to compile it:

```
ld: warning: symbol dyld_stub_binder not found, normally in libSystem.dylib
ld: entry point (newStart) undefined. for architecture x86_64
```

I'm running OS X 10.7 (Lion). Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `newStart()`, the corresponding symbol is `_newStart`. You should use that for the `-e` option:

```
gcc main.c -nostdlib -e _newStart -o min
```

See this Stack Overflow question about why underscores are prepended to (extern) function names: [Why do C compilers prepend underscores to external names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627511/557219)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you so much. Unfortunately this only leads to more questions... whenever I run the program I get "Illegal Instruction: 4" (apparently a core dump). Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: @semisight Compiling it with `-arch i386` solves the illegal instruction issue.