# How can C code call an external function without a leading underscore?

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang

Suppose I have a dylib (not written by me) that exports a function "Foo".  If I declare it as

```
extern "C" void Foo(void);
```

and try to call it, I get a linker error saying that `_Foo` is missing.  How can I deal with this without modifying the dylib?  Maybe some obscure linker flag, or Clang markup on the declaration, to make it not expect the underscore?

Comment: Are you using [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) and `dlsym` to get a pointer to the exported function?

Comment: @Praetorian: no, I was hoping not to have to get function pointers.

Comment: Does CLANG linker support DEF files?

Comment: @JWWalker Then you'll have to look for a linker option that lets you bind statically to a dylib. MSVC, for instance, can resolve function addresses from a DLL at link-time, thus avoiding having to manually `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to get a function pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a small number of these functions, its easiest to use a gcc/clang extension (perfect for OS X) to declare the external linkage to be assembly:

```
extern void Foo(void) asm ("Foo");
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1035937/1430833) for more detail.

Comment: Oh nice, this looks exactly what the OP wants. You can macroize this: `#define NO_UND(func) extern void func(void) asm(#func);`

Comment: Cool.  For the record, before this was posted, I thought of a somewhat less good approach:  Build a "glue" library using the linker's `-alias` or `-alias_list` option.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to load the function manually using `dlsym`:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void (*Foo)(void);

/* In some initialization function... */
Foo = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "Foo");
```