# Trying to create object files with make on Cygwin

Tags: gcc, assembly, makefile, x86, cygwin

I've just downloaded Cygwin and I've installed those useful packages from https://cygwin.mirror.constant.com library :

lynx, wget, curl, rsync, tar, bash-completion,make gcc-c, gcc-g++, gcc-fortran openssh and chere

I've seen on forums that they are the basic packages you should have. After this, I've tried to create object files with make in a folder with a makefile on it but here's the result:

> ```
> $ make
> gcc -g -m32 -g -Wall -c -o tp3.o tp3.c
> gcc -g -m32 -g -Wall -c -o equals.o equals.s
> gcc -g -m32 -g -Wall -c -o transpose.o transpose.s
> gcc -g -m32 -g -Wall -c -o multiply.o multiply.s
> gcc -g -m32 -g -Wall -c -o diagonal.o diagonal.s
> gcc -g -m32 -g -Wall -c -o average.o average.s
> gcc -g -m32 -g -Wall -o tp3 tp3.o equals.o transpose.o multiply.o diagonal.o average.o
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygwin
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [Makefile:18: tp3] Error 1
> ```

My `Makefile` looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -m32 -g -Wall
RM=rm -f
TARGET=tp3
OBJECTS=tp3.o equals.o transpose.o multiply.o diagonal.o average.o

.PHONY: clean

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.s.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

all: tp3

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) *.o $(TARGET)
```

An example of one of the assembly file `multiply.s`:

```
.globl matrix_multiply_asm

matrix_multiply_asm:
        push %ebp      /* save old base pointer */
        mov %esp, %ebp /* set ebp to current esp */

        /* Write your solution here */

        leave          /* restore ebp and esp */
        ret            /* return to the caller */
```

It compiles quietly well but a big error that I've tried to resolve comes right after it. It says that g is incompatible [...] when searching for -lgcc_s. When I work on Linux, I don't have this error. Can someone explain me what it means and what can I do? Also, I'm not quite sure what command to use to execute a file (.dat) after the make command on this terminal.

PS: The name of my current folder is tp3 and I have .c, .s and .dat files in it.

Comment: Please copy-paste relevant text into your question, rather than  post links to pictures of it.

Comment: You seem to have installed the 64 bit compiler only, so drop the `-m32` and hope your code is compatible :)

Comment: Did you ever resolve your problems?

Answer (score 1):

From the output I can tell you have installed 64-bit Cygwin. The 64-bit Cygwin `gcc`/`g++` that you have installed doesn't include the 32-bit libraries and support files. That causes the issue with the appropriate files not being found. Your `Makefile` appears to be generating 32-bit programs (`-m32` option)

You have a couple of choices:

- Make 64-bit executables and remove the `-m32` option in your `Makefile`. Since the assembly file templates your professor has given you have 32-bit prologue and epilogue this isn't really an option in your case. It appears they want you to create a 32-bit program.
- Make 32-bit executable with a 32-bit cross compiler

If you want 64-bit Cygwin to generate 32-bit programs you will need to rerun the installer and add these additional packages: `cygwin32-gcc-core` and `cygwin32-gcc-g++`

You will have to modify the Makefile so that you use `i686-pc-cygwin-gcc` instead of `gcc`. That can be done by modifying:

```
CC=gcc
```

to be:

```
CC=i686-pc-cygwin-gcc
```

`i686-pc-cygwin-gcc` is a Cygwin cross compiler that builds 32-bit (`i686`) programs and has a set of the 32-bit libraries and support files needed to generate 32-bit *C* programs.

The 32-bit Cygwin Windows cross compiler will require you to add leading underscores to the functions you mean to export (via `.globl` directive) to your *C* code. As an example your `multiply.s` file would have to look like:

```
.globl _matrix_multiply_asm  /* added leading underscore here */

_matrix_multiply_asm:        /* added leading underscore here */
        push %ebp      /* save old base pointer */
        mov %esp, %ebp /* set ebp to current esp */

        /* Write your solution here */

        leave          /* restore ebp and esp */
        ret            /* return to the caller */
```

You will have to make a similar change to each of the `.s` files. Once properly assembled and linked you can run it with the command:

```
./tp3.exe testmatrix2.dat
```

---

If you don't wish to add the underscores to the beginning of the exported functions in your `.s` files you can get your make file to add them for you with GCC's [`-fleading-underscore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034852/adding-leading-underscores-to-assembly-symbols-with-gcc-on-win32) option. You apply this to just the `.s` files. Your make file could then look like:

```
CC=i686-pc-cygwin-gcc
CFLAGS=-g -m32 -g -Wall
CFLAGS_AS=$(CFLAGS) -fleading-underscore
RM=rm -f
TARGET=tp3
OBJECTS=tp3.o
OBJECTS_AS=equals.o transpose.o multiply.o diagonal.o average.o

.PHONY: clean

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.s.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_AS) -c -o $@ $<

all: tp3

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS_AS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) *.o $(TARGET)
```

Comment: I suggest to just remove the `-m32`

Comment: @matzeri Did you see option `Make 64-bit executables and remove the -m32 option in your Makefile` in my answer. Problem is that his assignment requires 32-bit as they are expected to fill in their code between existing  function prologue/epilogue that specifically use 32-bit. My original answer (see the edits) weighed more heavily on the first option, until I found the exact assignment (with all files) then I opted in favor of the answer which uses 32-bit code. You have to realize original question the OP posted was w/o a lot of context. heavily edited his question once I found the assignment.

Comment: @matzeri : so I suggested that as an option, but pointed out why in this assignment that may not be an option. It may be for someone else, which is why I mentioned it. For this assignment, 32-bit may be a requirement. And it is a good exercise to see how you can do this on Cygwin.

Comment: If 32bit is a requirement, he/she can use a Cygwin32 bit installation. Cross compilation seems an additional complication.