# Forward reference (_telldir)

Tags: macos, include, inline-assembly, forward-reference

In the file /usr/include/dirent.h of MacOSX10.14 I see this line:

```
struct _telldir;        /* forward reference */
```

In the same file the identifier is used:

```
 struct _telldir *__dd_td;
```

Nowhere else in the include files is _telldir defined but in the same file the function telldir is declared:

```
long telldir(DIR *) __DARWIN_ALIAS_I(telldir);
```

I see the __DARWIN_ALIAS_I macro is defined as

```
#define __DARWIN_ALIAS_I(sym)       __asm("_" __STRING(sym) __DARWIN_SUF_64_BIT_INO_T __DARWIN_SUF_UNIX03)**
```

I understand this is "inline assembler" and that this defines _telldir but I would like to know more about this definition.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly inline asm as in *instructions*, it's just overriding the name mangling for symbol names.  (e.g. `static int foo` on MacOS normally has a symbol name of `_foo`.  e.g. in the compiler asm output, you'd have `_foo: .long 0`).

In GNU C, `int foo asm("foobar");` has an **asm symbol name** of `foobar` instead of the default `_foo`.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html and this SO answer: [Adding leading underscores to assembly symbols with GCC on Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034852/adding-leading-underscores-to-assembly-symbols-with-gcc-on-win32/1035937#1035937)

Try it yourself on https://godbolt.org/ if you're curious.

---

In this case, we have **C preprocessor string literal concatenation** of the macro expansions.  e.g.

```
"_" "telldir" "_ino64"
```

is exactly equivalent to `"_telldir_ino64"` in all contexts, including in
 `long telldir(DIR *dirp)  asm("_" "telldir" "_ino64");`

This use-case appears to be choosing which `telldir` implementation in libc by setting the name based on a few other CPP macros.  So if `__DARWIN_SUF_64_BIT_INO_T` is defined as `"_ino64"` and `__DARWIN_SUF_UNIX03` is defined as empty or `/**/`, then this sets the symbol name to `"_telldir_ino64"`

(No idea how MacOS would typically actually define those other macros, but the syntax of the line you show is just string literal concatenation inside an `asm("")` to set the symbol name.)

Comment: Thanks Peter for you very detailed explanation, however I'm still a bit baffled by the syntax of __asm("xxx") which according to your answer is used to change the function name in symbol table. I googled a lot but can't find such usage, the closest one is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/using-operators-in-asm-blocks?view=msvc-170 but it only mentions __asm{...} where ... is actual assembly code. Could you collaborate more? Much appreciated.

Comment: @mzoz: My answer links the docs for this usage of it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html .  If you want the C name to be `foo()`, but the compiler to emit `call bar` in the asm, you use `int foo(void) asm("bar")`.

Comment: cool got it so __asm is just a macos variant of asm in gcc

Comment: @mzoz: GCC and clang both accept `asm`, `__asm__`, and `__asm` as equivalent for all targets.  In `-std=c11` mode (instead of the default `-std=gnu11`), `asm` isn't recognized, to keep the namespace clean.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html .    It seems `_asm` is only MSVC.  https://godbolt.org/z/jv9nTvrGK  IDK why MacOS devs picked `__asm` instead of the GCC-documented `__asm__`.  Maybe clang does document `__asm`.