# Refer to external symbol without leading underscore from C

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I am trying to refer to object files generated by clang from ObjC sources from C code, however the compiler is generating symbols not prepended by underscore so extern specification does not work. I'm using the latest Apple clang. I am guessing this must be possible, since kernels would need to do this. Anyone confirm it is possible or not, if so how to do it, if not, a workaround if known please. Thanks!

Comment: I seem to recall there is a function `__attribute__` to do this, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Did you look up the compiler's option to not prepend the underscore?

Comment: Near duplicate of [Adding leading underscores to assembly symbols with GCC on Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034852)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I found the answer immediately after posting the question:

`extern void *name asm("name");`

appears to work with both clang and gcc. Not sure about Windows.